# Can I padding/margin left of Microsoft Chart Controls to start bar at tick mark?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, charts, controls

I just begin use MS Chart Control to display transaction amount based on timeline.

This's I did.

[image]

But this's I want to

[image]

Can I ship or right move every bar to start at tick mark?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure what your code looks like, but from [align first bar column center with the x-axis label](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/99c111d9-34b8-4dc9-9b58-72c6784cdde1/align-first-bar-column-center-with-the-xaxis-label?forum=MSWinWebChart), I would suggest something like this `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.MajorTickMark.IntervalOffset = 0.5`, and change the 0.5 to meet your requirements.

Comment: Could you add a little more detail to your question? It's a little unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your answer help my work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Danial, this's a result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iImBZ.jpg)

My job's represent the data of passenger/parcel amount passed through the company transportation.

```
barchart1.Series.Add("Passenger")
    barchart1.Series("Passenger").XValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.String
    barchart1.Series("Passenger").XValueMember = "Hour"
    barchart1.Series("Passenger").YValueMembers = "PassengerAmount"
    barchart1.Series("Passenger").IsValueShownAsLabel = True
    barchart1.Series("Passenger").Item("PointWidth") = 0.8
    barchart1.Series("Passenger").PostBackValue = "#VALX"
    barchart1.Series("Passenger").BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    barchart1.Series("Passenger").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedColumn

    barchart1.Series.Add("Parcel")
    barchart1.Series("Parcel").XValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.String
    barchart1.Series("Parcel").XValueMember = "Hour"
    barchart1.Series("Parcel").YValueMembers = "ParcelAmount"
    barchart1.Series("Parcel").IsValueShownAsLabel = True
    barchart1.Series("Parcel").Item("PointWidth") = 0.8
    barchart1.Series("Parcel").PostBackValue = "#VALX"
    barchart1.Series("Parcel").BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    barchart1.Series("Parcel").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedColumn

    barchart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -45
    barchart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
    barchart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
    barchart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
    barchart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = False
    barchart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LineColor = Drawing.Color.Transparent
    barchart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = False
    barchart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.MajorTickMark.IntervalOffset = 0.6
    barchart1.Legends.Add(New DataVisualization.Charting.Legend("Legend2"))
```

It will more understand if the bar start at begin of each time tick.

Thanks again